# How to tell ASP.NET MVC to include cshtml in every view in folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my problem:

For one controller `ProjectsController.cs` I want that every view would include some razor code.

For now I have something like this:

In `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` I render optional section `header`:

```
     ...</div>
</div>
@RenderSection("header", false)
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>...
```

Then in my `View/Projects` folder I have created partial view `_ProjectsPartial.cshtml`

[image]

And I include in every view in Projects folder header section, so `Views/Projects/Index.cshtml` and `Views/Projects/Console.cshtml` have this included:

```
@section header
{
    @Html.Partial("_ProjectsPartial")
}
```

It works, as it should but I have a feeling this is not the way to do it, and I need to include this `@section header` in every view under `Views/Projects` which is not ideal, as I want to add many views in the future in this folder.

**So my question is, what is the best way to do it?**

I know I could use other layout for all these views adding and using `Views/Projects/_ViewStart.cshtml` but then I would need to duplicate main layout code as I don't know how to merge one layout into other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can try:

At first, just put the following code snippets into your `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`.

```
@RenderSection("header", false)
@if (!IsSectionDefined("header"))
{
    @Html.Partial("_ProjectsPartial")
}
```

Then put the `@section header` into your views when needed.

```
@section header
{
    @Html.Partial("_ProjectsPartial")
}
```

By the way, the Layout view is also a view. So you can treat a layout as a view and it can have it's own Layout by assigning `@{ Layout = "new_layout.cshtml"; }`.  Then you can combined two Layouts without duplicated content in it.

Comment: Thanks for help, but even without trying I am pretty sure it will force all views that don't have defined header section to have this partial site for Projects. It could be because you don't see my main problem which is adding automatically to any view in certain folder some razor or just plain html code.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski The Layout view is also a view.  So you can treat a layout as a view and it can have it's own Layout by assigning `@{ Layout = "new_layout.cshtml"; }`.  Then you can combined two Layouts without duplicated content in it.

Comment: Ah great, that would work! I will check it tomorrow and if you edit your answer with this and it will work I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @JerrySwitalski My answer has been edited. HTH. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have time to check it, but will soon.